# jetty security-constraint auth-constraint role-name * (asterisk) fails

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, security

I'm learning Jetty embedded ( jetty-all-8.1.3.v20120416.jar ) and I have a dead simple servlet that I've enabled a `<security-constraint>` (HTTP BASIC) on. My two unit tests that check authorization correctly pass and fail (one makes the request using the username and password in my realm.properties, and the other tries to connect with no authentication) when I have `<role-name>users</role-name>`, but fail for `<role-name>*</role-name>`. JUnit summary of incorrect results (see method definitions below):

> ```
> testPingServletAuthenticated(): Expected: OK, Actual: Forbidden
> testPingServletUnauthenticated(): Passed
> ```

File snippets are included below ('====' separates them). I hope that's enough information. Thanks in advance! -- matt

==== web.xml ====

```
servlet-mapping
  servlet-name: hello-servlet
  url-pattern: /hello-web-xml

security-constraint
  url-pattern: /*
  auth-constraint:
    role-name: users

login-config
  auth-method: BASIC
  realm-name: test security realm

security-role
  role-name: users
```

==== realm.properties ====

```
theuser:password,users
```

==== HelloServlet.java ====

```
very simple doGet()
```

==== JettySetupTest.java ====

```
public static void startJettyServer() throws Exception {
    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setDescriptor("out/artifacts/diy_embedded_testing_war_exploded/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    webAppContext.setResourceBase("out/artifacts/diy_embedded_testing_war_exploded/");
    webAppContext.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
    webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);    // Q: needed?

    LoginService loginService = new HashLoginService("test security realm", "test/embed/realm.properties"); // NB: must match realm name in web.xml's <login-config><realm-name>
    webAppContext.getSecurityHandler().setLoginService(loginService);

    SERVER = new Server(PORT);
    SERVER.setHandler(webAppContext);
    SERVER.start();
}


@Test
public void testPingServletAuthenticated() throws IOException {
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(BASE_URL + "/hello-web-xml");     // http://localhost:8080/app/hello-web-xml
    webResource.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("theuser", "password"));
    ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .get(ClientResponse.class);     // @GET
    assertEquals(ClientResponse.Status.OK, clientResponse.getClientResponseStatus());
    assertEquals(HelloServlet.GREETING + "\n", clientResponse.getEntity(String.class));
}


@Test
public void testPingServletUnauthenticated() throws IOException {
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(BASE_URL + "/hello-web-xml");     // http://localhost:8080/app/hello-web-xml
    ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .get(ClientResponse.class);     // @GET
    assertEquals(ClientResponse.Status.UNAUTHORIZED, clientResponse.getClientResponseStatus());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had a basic misunderstanding of how `<role-name>` is used in web.xml. I thought that if I used "*" in `<security-constraint><auth-constraint><role-name>`, then it should also be listed in `<security-role><role-name>`. However, I figured out that the latter should list actual roles used in the app, in my case "users".